# Css - styling issue across browsers - nav bar

Tags: html, css

I've been wracking my brain on how I can solve this issue, but I don't know what to do to solve it...

The issue is that on Chrome my navigation and css styles work perfectly, but on other browsers it looks all f'ed up.

On Chrome - looks correct!

On IE- I lose the navigation bar styles

On Firefox - the navigation bar is there, but none of the site images are showing up

My site is here:

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only answer we can give based on how broad your question is is that you need to read up on browser discrepancies. IE is the biggest culprit as it tends to veer the most away from web standards.

Comment: Please post a short but working example here, so when you fix your site this question will still be of use to future visitors.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Also, you've been around a while, so you should know that we're [not fans](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64509/130770) of [obfuscated URLs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113660/130770).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues right off the bat. Your images aren't showing up because the relative paths are formatted incorrectly. you have "imgVideoTagger\CenterCredits.png" (with a back slash). it should be a forward-slash.  Also, for the width and height attributes in HTML, it should just be the number, so instead of "315px" it should be "315".

You also have some basic HTML errors, such as stray end tags.

In order to debug your issues, I recommend using the W3C html validator service: http://validator.w3.org/

Fixing the errors you find there may resolve your nav issue in IE as well.

Additionally - since you're declaring your page HTML 5, I recommend leveraging more of the HTML5 semantic goodness, ditching any depreciated tags like `<center>`, and using something like modernizr so IE can recognize those newer elements. This also might help out with the nav since `<nav>` is an HTML5 tag.